# Possible PHP function to match two keywords without regex

Tags: php, regex, strpos

I've been using stripos to match single keyword within a string, however you can only define the input string, string to search and the offset... Is there a function or way i could require two keywords to be found. Such as Happy and Birthday, which would be match Happy 21st Birthday or Happy Freaking Birthday by defining both, Happy and Birthday separately. So that the match would come back false unless both keywords are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously regex is more efficient, but you'd have to do:

```
if(strpos($yourString,"Happy") !== false && strpos($yourString,"Birthday") !== false){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: `!== FALSE` is a better test. strpos returns false on no-match, which'll get cast to 0 for the inequality for a false positive

Comment: you sure regex is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

```
return strpos($keyword1, ...) !== false && strpos($keyword2) !== false
```

Comment: I think this'd give you a false negative should one of the words appear at the begining of the string (offset 0).  Compare with `!== false`

Comment: Correct, need to do proper bool type check on strpos

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is probably just to and two `strpos` calls

```
$twoNeedles = function($n1,$n2,$hay,$caseIns=false)
                {
                  $f = $caseIns ? 'stripos' : 'strpos';
                  return ($f($hay, $n1) !== false) 
                      && ($f($hay, $n2) !== false);};

echo $twoNeedles('Happy', 'Birthday', 'Happy Freakin Birthday d00d'); //true
echo $twoNeedles('Happy', 'Ice Cream', 'Happy Freakin Birthday d00d'); //false
echo $twoNeedles('HaPpY', 'bIrTH', 'Happy Freakin Birthday d00d', true); //true
```

And since i love to overthink

```
$manyNeedles =  function($n,$hay,$caseIns=false)
                {
                  $c = $caseIns ? 'stripos' : 'strpos';
                  $f = function($a,$b) use ($c,$hay) 
                         {return $a && ($c($b,$hay) !== false);};
                  return array_reduce($n,$f,true);
                };

$myNeedles = array('happy', 'birthday', 'to', 'you');
echo $manyNeedles($myNeedles, 'hap hap happy birf birthday to j000000 and you');
```

And now I better quit before i do it with `implode` and `eval` instead of reduce

Comment: That'll fail if the 'needle' is at position 0 in the 'haystack'. One or both of the `ands` will be 0 and evaluate to a boolean false overall.

Comment: This would work but im looking for the least amount of code since i have to implement a lot of keywords. Had to up vote for the awesome test strings.

Comment: im not sure i make the connection.  you know you only need to declare the function once right?  call it 100 times after.  more importantly tho, glad you liked the test strings =P